# Check correct order of messages in Kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elk

In my logs, some messages should appear in the same order. But for some reason, the order is swapped in failure case. Is it somehow possible in Kibana to set up monitoring or dashboard for swapped messages? E.g. when an Alarm-Clear event arrives before an Alarm-Set event.

Between Set and Clear, there are usually less than two seconds. So, a solution would also be to wait two seconds after the Set event for the Clear event.

More specific, there are messages send over a message bus and received by ELK. The sending system sends the messages in correct order but looking at Kibana Discover, the order is swapped. This I want to detect in Kibana.

Some example from the sending system:

```
2023-05-03 07:40:09,535 [Queue.Package:28] INFO Send=<<AlarmID>135</AlarmID><AlarmText>AlarmSet</AlarmText>>
2023-05-03 07:40:09,535 [Queue.Package:28] INFO Send=<<AlarmID>135</AlarmID><AlarmText>AlarmClear</AlarmText>>
```

In ELK Discover, AlarmClear before AlarmSet visible.

Comment: If you can share an example document, current sorting results, and expected results I can help you.

Comment: Hi Dogan, thank you! I added an example. But would be nice to have a general solution to detect missing entries :)

Comment: you're welcome. Which method did you follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions for that. the first solution will help you to solve the problem. The second solution will help you to detect the problem.

### 1.solution

Use the original timestamp for the data before queueing and/or indexing data into elasticsearch. For logstash, you can use the [date filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-examples.html).

### 2.solution

Use [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-examples.html) and aggregate the data according to `AlarmID`. Transform API will create a new index and you can calculate the diff between `AlarmSet - AlarmClear`.